# How to remove localhost from URL

Tags: xampp, localhost

For years now I have been running my sites using Xampp and they all follow the same url path, something like `http://localhost/my_site`

How does one configure Xampp to use only `http://my_site` like I have seen in so many tutorial videos by others? Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you using windows find vhosts file at windows/system32/drivers/vhost then open that file as administrator then add your  /my_site as 127.0.0.1